# SetProp problem

Tags: c, winapi

Can anybody tell me why the following code doesn't work? I don't get any compiler errors.

```
short value = 10;
SetProp(hCtl, "value", (short*) value);
```

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"?  What do you expect to happen? What does happen?

Comment: Nothing happens. When I check the value using `GetProp(hCtl, "value")`, it returns 0.

Comment: Casts are almost always wrong. When I see a cast, my first impulse is to delete it. Without the cast the computer complains ... so increase the warning level of your compiler and **mind the warnings**.

Comment: @pmg, you're right in this case - it's the OP's cast that is wrong.  @Midas - you probably want to read the documentation for `SetProp()`... that third parameter is supposed to be a `HANDLE`.

Comment: What does SetProp return ? Does GetLastError say anything useful ?

Comment: `HANDLE` is defined like this: `typedef PVOID HANDLE`. Doesn't that mean a pointer to any data type?

Comment: @Midas - probably yes.  But you didn't make a pointer, you just typecast your value into a pointer type.  You probably want `&value`.

Comment: In this case, the cast is unlikely to be the problem. Usually casting a non-HANDLE to a HANDLE is a sign of a bug, but SetProp explicitly allows this usage. From MSDN: "A window property is any data assigned to a window. A window property is usually a handle of the window-specific data, but it may be any value." ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632594(v=VS.85).aspx )

Comment: Information that would be useful here: Where is hCtl from - is it a window in your own process, or another process? What is the return value of SetProp? Have you verified that the HWND specified by hCtl is still valid when you call GetProp later on, and that hCtl itself has the same value then? More information on what you are trying to do here would help.

Comment: @Carl Norum: in this case, you likely don't want &value: SetProp just takes the pointer value and stores it blindly; it doesn't care if it's even a real value. Think of it as dwUserData, but with an unusual type. The problem with saving &value in this case is that you save the address of a variable that's (apparently) on the stack, which won't do you any good later on. Bizarrely (even by Win32 standards!), casting the value itself is actually the right thing to do here - Get/SetProp is perhaps the one Win32 API where a cast is nearly always right. (See MSDN link in above comment.)

Comment: See also MSDN at this other link for an example where SetProp is used with a cast of a non-HANDLE value to a HANDLE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773183(v=vs.85).aspx . Part of the problem here is that the page for SetProp itself reads somewhat ambiguously: it's not made clear if it's the entity that the HANDLE refers to that can be anything, or if binary value of the HANDLE itself can be anything. The other two MSDN articles clarify this.

Comment: @Midas - Considering that `GetProp` doesn't return what you want, you should probably post your code that calls `GetProp` as well.

Comment: It seems to be fixed now... I tried to find what fixed it, but I couldn't find what it is. It seems that the code that I originally had was actually right! There must have been a problem with the `HWND hCtl`. Thanks to everyone for your great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third parameter is typed as a `HANDLE`, so IMO to meet the explicit contract of the function you should save the property as a `HANDLE` by allocating a `HGLOBAL` memory block.  However, as noted in the comments below, MSDN states that any value can be specified, and indeed when I try it on Windows 7 using...

```
SetProp(hWnd, _T("TestProp"), (HANDLE)(10)); // or (HANDLE)(short*)(10)
...
(short)GetProp(hWnd, _T("TestProp"));
```

... I get back 10 from GetProp.  I suspect somewhere between your SetProp and GetProp one of two things happens: (1) the value of hWnd is different -- you're checking a different window or (2) a timing issue -- the property hasn't been set yet or had been removed.

---

If you wanted to use an `HGLOBAL` instead to follow the specific types of the function signature, you can follow [this example in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633561%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#adding_property).

Even though a `HANDLE` is just a pointer, it's a specific data type that is allocated by calls into the Windows API.  Lots of things have handles: icons, cursors, files, ... Unless the documentation explicitly states otherwise, to use a blob of data such as a `short` when the function calls for a `HANDLE`, you need a memory handle (an `HGLOBAL`).

The sample code linked above copies data as a string, but you can instead set it as another data type:

```
// TODO: Add error handling
hMem = GlobalAlloc(GPTR, sizeof(short));
lpMem = GlobalLock(hMem);
if (lpMem != NULL)
{
    *((short*)lpMem) = 10;
    GlobalUnlock(hMem);
}
```

To read it back, when you `GetProp` to get the `HANDLE` you must lock it to read the memory:

```
// TODO: Add error handling
short val;
hMem = (HGLOBAL)GetProp(hwnd, ...); 
if (hMem)
{
    lpMem = GlobalLock(hMem);
    if (lpMem)
    {
        val = *((short*)lpMem);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not true: while it is actually typed as HANDLE, MSDN does state that it can be any value: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632594(v=VS.85).aspx : A window property is any data assigned to a window. A window property is usually a handle of the window-specific data, but it may be any value.

Comment: You are correct.  I just tested it on Windows 7, and calling `SetProp(hWnd, "PropName", (HANDLE)(short*)(10))` does work.  Wonder if maybe previous versions of Windows required it to actually be a `HANDLE`, then they relaxed it in a later version?  It doesn't work for the OP...

Comment: Also works on XP too... That's the oldest version of Windows I have to test with.

Comment: It seems that the code that I originally had actually did work. There must have been some other problem in my code...

Answer (score 0):

I would create the `short` on the heap, so that it continues to exist, or perhaps make it global, which is perhaps what you did.  Also the cast for the `short` address needs to be `void *`, or `HANDLE`.